How to calculate the effective permittivity of a material exposed to an electric field of a square wave?
Sorry if this is more of an engineering question, but i think it fits the forum.
I want to calculate the capacitance of a capacitor which is made out of a comb like structure (compare the ascii art below). This capacitor is part of an astable multivibrator circuit with a 555 Timer, so that the capacitor is charged through a resistor until the voltage between it is 2/3 of the supply voltage, where it then switches to get decharged until 1/3 of the supply voltage.
This basically results in a voltage of a square wave being applied to the capacitor. The capacitor has a dielectric (water) on top of it, whose permittivity is dependant on the frequency of the electric field.
How do i calculate the effective permittivity of the water for a frequency of the square wave?
I thought about using the coefficients of the fourier series of a square wave to weight the different permittivities at the different harmonics, but i think thats not right, as the sum of all the coefficients diverges (they don't cancel each other out anymore because of the time dependace)
For more context: This is used in a sensor I'm working on which is supposed to detect ice and water on its surface (right now it's only qualitative)
Thank you in advance, if anything is missing please tell me
____________________________________square_wave(t)
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
  |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯GND

